# How to find the next class from table which has a text value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to calculate the consumed volume from a table from each day (date with it's previous date).
When there are no table rows with empty volumes, this works correct.
But when there are some table rows which have empty volumes, it fails.
In code below you can see what i mean:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-15</td>
    <td class="volume">80</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td> // text 30 (110 - 80)
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume">110</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td> // text 50 (160 - 110)
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-13</td>
    <td class="volume">160</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td> // text 60 (220 - 160)
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-12</td>
    <td class="volume">220</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td> 
  </tr>
</table>

$('.volume').each(function() {
  const next = $(this).parent().next().find('.volume')
  $(this).siblings('.consumed').html(+next.html() - $(this).html())
})
```

Above works great but it fails when my table looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-15</td>
    <td class="volume">80</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-15</td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume">110</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-13</td>
    <td class="volume">160</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-13</td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-12</td>
    <td class="volume">220</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a fiddle how it should look like: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvjzs069/5/)

So i need something like:

```
$('.volume').each(function() {
  const next = $(this).parent().next().find('.volume')// find next volume if not empty!
  $(this).siblings('.consumed').html(+next.html() - $(this).html()) // which belongs to a volume which is not empty!
```

Comment: So if it empty, what should happen?? You lacked to tell us what you expect to happen in this case. Is it zero? Is it the previous value? What is it????

Comment: yes, if empty, you should ignore it and find the first which has a text val and calculate with that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get all next `tr` elements from the current one and then filter out the ones without the text and then take the first one from that result and that will be your next value.

```js
$('.volume').each(function() {
  const currentValue = $(this).text();
  const nextValue = $(this)
    .parent('tr')
    .nextAll('tr')
    .filter(function() {
      return $(this).find('.volume').text().length;
    }).first().find('.volume').text()

  if (currentValue && nextValue) {
    $(this).next('.consumed').text(
      Number(nextValue) - Number(currentValue)
    )
  }
})
```

```css
td.date, td.volume, td.consumed {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Without empty volumes: shows correct</h1>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Vol</th>
      <th>Consumed</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-15</td>
    <td class="volume">80</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume">110</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-13</td>
    <td class="volume">160</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-12</td>
    <td class="volume">220</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!----------------------------------------------->
<br /><br />
<h1>With some empty volumes; now it fails</h1>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Vol</th>
      <th>Consumed</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-15</td>
    <td class="volume">80</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-15</td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume">110</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-13</td>
    <td class="volume">160</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-13</td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-12</td>
    <td class="volume">220</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Awesome solution! Exactly what i was looking for. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

`+next.html()` will create a [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) when there isn't a value there. Try `+(next.html() || $(this).html())` instead.

```js
$('.volume').each(function() {
  const next = $(this).parent().next().find('.volume')
  var next_val = +(next.html() || $(this).html());
  $(this).siblings('.consumed').html(next_val - $(this).html())
})
```

```css
td{
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-15</td>
    <td class="volume">80</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-15</td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume">110</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-13</td>
    <td class="volume">160</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-13</td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-12</td>
    <td class="volume">220</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried this in the fiddle but unfortunately without result

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to attack it, look for the volume elements with text, do not select the trs elements.

```js
var volumeElems = $(".volume").not(":empty");
volumeElems.each(function(index, elem){
  if (index===volumeElems.length-1) return;
  const currentElem = $(elem);
  const curr = +currentElem.text();
  const prev = +volumeElems.eq(index+1).text();
  currentElem.next().text(prev-curr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-15</td>
    <td class="volume">80</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-15</td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume">110</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-14</td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-13</td>
    <td class="volume">160</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-13</td>
    <td class="volume"></td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">2021-08-12</td>
    <td class="volume">220</td>
    <td class="consumed"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```